# i want to keyword serach api with the third party amazon-ads

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-advertising-api

I have find the in
https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/en-us/guides/reporting/v2/metrics#performance-metrics

I am not able to find the keywordSearch api

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const axios = require('axios');

AWS.config.update({region: 'your_aws_region'});

async function searchByKeyword(keyword) {
    const apiKey = 'YOUR_THIRD_PARTY_API_KEY';
    const apiUrl = `https://api.example.com/search?keyword=${
        encodeURIComponent(keyword)
    }`;

    try {
        const response = await axios.get(apiUrl, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${apiKey}`
            }
        });

        const data = response.data;
        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error while making the API request:', error.message);
        throw error;
    }
}
```

I have tried this but I want url of search keyword api.